# Get name of the column with last value in the row

Tags: pandas

I am doing cohort analysis and the dataset I'm using has 15 months as the name as columns with revenue and around 7k user_id rows.
I need to get a new column with the month when the user was last time active.

| 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 |
| --- | --- |
| 3456. | Nan |
| Nan. | 8679 |

Result should be like this

| 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 | Last_month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3456. | Nan | 2021-01-01 |
| Nan. | 8679 | 2021-02-01 |

I have tried few options but it didnt work

users.apply(pd.Series.last_valid_index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {'2021-01-01': {0: 3456, 1: None}, '2021-02-01': {0: None, 1: 8679}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    2021-01-01  2021-02-01
0   3456.0      NaN
1   NaN         8679.0
```

**Code**

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.last_valid_index(), axis=1)
```

output:

```
0    2021-01-01
1    2021-02-01
dtype: object
```

**full Code**

make output to `Last_month` column

```
df.assign(Last_month=df.apply(lambda x: x.last_valid_index(), axis=1))
```

result:

```
    2021-01-01  2021-02-01  Last_month
0   3456.0      NaN         2021-01-01
1   NaN         8679.0      2021-02-01
```

Answer (score 1):

using a boolean and `idxmax()` might be the solution here

```
df['last_month'] = (~df.isna()).idxmax(axis=1)


print(df)


  2021-01-01 2021-02-01  last_month
0       3456        NaN  2021-01-01
1        NaN       8679  2021-02-01
```